# How we can do grouping of scenarios in Karate script?

Tags: grouping, karate

I want to segregate the scenarios as per the requirement like grouping scenarios for regression , smoke and so on. how we can implement this ??

Answer (score 0):

Use "tags", documented here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#tags

```
@sometagname
Scenario:
```

And you can choose tags via the command-line: https://github.com/intuit/karate#test-suites